# Regex to validate for Unique Well Identifier in rails

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I am a regex newbie and can't seem to figure this one out.

Here is a link to the required string formats:

http://earth.gov.bc.ca/royp-bin/phcgi.exe?PH_QKC=DOCUWI&PH_APP=RMSprodApp&PH_HTML=DOCUWI.htm

For example:

100041506421W500 = 1+0+{01-16}+{01-36}+{001-129}+{01-36}+W+{1-6}+0+{0-9}

I tried this:

```
^10[0|2-9]{1}0*([1-9]|1[0-6])0*([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-6])0*([1-9][0-9]|1[0-2][0-9])0*([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-6])W[1-6]0[0-9]$
```

In a regex validator and it sort of works except that 1041506421W500 and 10000000041506421W500 validates.  The entire string can only be 16 characters long.

I am pretty sure I am missing something obvious here regarding the leading zeros.  Tried the NTS format and running into the same sort of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I straightened it out according to your spec:

```
1+0+{01-16}+{01-36}+{001-129}+{01-36}+W+{1-6}+0+{0-9}
```

Here it is expanded with some comments:

```
^
1
0
[0|2-9]                           // match 0 or 2-9 (is this missing from your spec?)
(0[1-9]|1[0-6])                   // match 01-09 or 10-16
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-6])         // match 01-09 or 10-29 or 30-36
(00[1-9]|0[1-9][0-9]|1[0-2][0-9]) // match 001-009 or 010-099 or 100-129
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-6])         // match 01-09 or 10-29 or 30-36
W
[1-6]
0
[0-9]
$
```

And here it is all put together:

```
^10[0|2-9](0[1-9]|1[0-6])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-6])(00[1-9]|0[1-9][0-9]|1[0-2][0-9])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-6])W[1-6]0[0-9]$
```

Comment: I had deleted that first 0|2-9 by mistake before I pasted it in.  After seeing this I can't believe I didn't figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

> For example:

```
100041506421W500 = 1+0+{01-16}+{01-36}+{001-129}+{01-36}+W+{1-6}+0+{0-9}
```

This is already wrong, cause `100041506421W500` is 1+0+00

Things like `0*([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-6])` is also wrong, cause allow variable length and you have fixed length parts.

And the main problem is regexp itself. You'd better use just `substr` and `to_i`.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem you mean is the quantifier `*`. It means 0 or more.

If you want those zeros to be optional, use a `?` as quantifier, means 0 or 1. Means change your `0*` to `0?`.

And the quantifier `{1}` is superfluous, you can just delete it.